# What does ## and % mean in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

We had to get the 'filename' and 'file extension' from a string

```
[sathish@oc Desktop]$ export FILE="filename.txt"
```

The following syntax works fine.  However, we would like to understand how '##*.' and '%.*' works

```
[sathish@oc Desktop]$ echo ${FILE##*.}
txt
[sathish@oc Desktop]$ echo ${FILE%.*}
filename
```

Any help would be nice

Comment: Why not read the manual? For bash it is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). See the "Parameter Expansion" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting point would be to read the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), especially the section on [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion-1).

Some relevant excerpts:

`${parameter#word}`

`${parameter##word}`

The word
is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
expansion (see Filename Expansion).  If the pattern matches
the beginning of the expanded value of parameter,
then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter
with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the
longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted.
If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’,
the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
If parameter is an array variable subscripted with
‘@’ or ‘*’,
the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the
array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

`${parameter%word}`

`${parameter%%word}`

The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in
filename expansion.
If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of
parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of
parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case)
or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted.
If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’,
the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
If parameter
is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’,
the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the
array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.